# Wine application runs from generated Launcher, but not from console

Tags: launcher, wine, console

I have installed a Windows application through wine, and it launches perfectly through the generated launcher, however, when I use the exact same commands the launcher uses, but to invoke the program from the console, I just get errors and warnings but no application.

Is there something I'm missing here? do I have to specify the output to be to something else besides the console?

#### Update

I apologize for the lack of information given in my original post. Here some extra info that might help better understanding the problem.

This is the actual command I'm using to invoke the program from the console, It's the exact same command the Launcher uses to successfully start the program.

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/carmen/.wine" wine C:\\Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\\Gamenext\\The\ Rise\ of\ Atlantis\\The_Rise_of_Atlantis.exe
```

These are the errors I get using the above command.

```
fixme:d3d:check_fbo_compat Format WINED3DFMT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM with rendertarget flag is not supported as FBO color attachment, and no fallback specified.
fixme:d3d:check_fbo_compat Format WINED3DFMT_B10G10R10A2_UNORM with rendertarget flag is not supported as FBO color attachment, and no fallback specified.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f880,0x00000000), stub!
```

Thanks again in advance everyone.

Comment: What are the 'errors and warnings' you get?

Comment: Also specify the commands as well.

Comment: -1, for not giving the warning. It is really really very hard to say anything without seeing nothing. We don't and can't read mind

Comment: Sorry guys about the lack of information, I edited the post, and it hopefully makes more sense, thanks again in advance for taking the time to look at it, even with its initial shortcomings.

Comment: Changed the -1 to +1. :)